# Are there ad blocker that filters YouTube advertisements on Mojave Safari Version 12.0?

Tags: safari, mojave, software-recommendation

Who knows an AdBlocker for the latest Safari that is able to block youtube ads. I've tried AdBlock & AdBlock Plus which both are now 'full' applications instead of extensions.

- AdBlockPlus slows down your browser to the point that entering text, or clicking a link has a lag of around 1.5 ~ 2 seconds.
- AdBlock works for a while, and then hangs taking 600% cpu utilization.

It works again after dis&enabling it in the extension preferences. But AdBlock's biggest problem is it doesn't block that much on youtube.

I'm not here to ask how to get AdBlock or AdBlockPlus going. I'm here to ask who has a blocker for youtube.

I've used AdBlock in the past before the new extension architecture, and it blocked all youtube ads. Now YouTube is encoding the advertisements in to the streams and come up with harder to block advertisements.

Can anyone recommend software that either blocks more or uses less CPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use  [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari/) with Safari 12 on macOS Mojave. It has been several months since I watched an Youtube ad.

This blog was of extreme help in making the extension work using extension builder. It also has an AppleScript to enable the extension quickly.

- https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/install-any-safari-extension-macos-mojave/

I couldn't get preferences saving to work, so I export the settings to a file and import it back after every safari restart.

Unfortunately, the extension system has been removed from Safari in Safari 13. So I plan to switch to [Brave](https://brave.com) or [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/) to continue using uBlock Origin.

- https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari/issues/158
- https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari/issues/156

For safari, uBO suggests

- [Adguard](https://adguard.com/en/article/how-to-block-ads-on-youtube.html)
- Ka-Block!
- Ghostery lite
- Wipr

NOT recommended:

- uBlock (not origin)
- AdBlock Plus for Safari
- AdBlock for Safari (made by BETAFISH INC)

*Not affiliated with any product.*

Comment: When I try to install `Adguard`, I am getting following error: `“AdGuard won’t start correctly! Some AdGuard services were not started correctly. Please contact the support team.”`

Answer (score 2):

"Wipr" does the Job guys. No slowdowns, no cpu hogging, and it's not able to get to your passwords & payment info.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wipr/id1320666476?mt=12

Edit: Wipr no longer blocks YT ads.