# What adblock extension works on macOS Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

How can I block ads in Safari 14 on macOS Big Sur?

Most mainstream adblockers don't support Safari or don't block ads or cause websites like YouTube to stop working.

I've tried

- wipr
- Adblock Plus
- Adblock
- uBlock

Are there any Safari-compatible adblockers that actually work?

Comment: I have a Apple Silicon mac mini and App Store says wipr works on this machine and AppStore lists several other extensions  So please explain how these do not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to block ads in Safari without installing anything?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426296/how-to-block-ads-in-safari-without-installing-anything)

Comment: Did you check out the blockers listed in the Safari Extensions section of the App Store?

Comment: @nohillside adblock, adblock plus, and wipr came from there and break sites

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the individual configurations you make? I'm using 1blocker and need to tweak the rules now and then to make some sites work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there ad blocker that filters YouTube advertisements on Mojave Safari Version 12.0?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340844/are-there-ad-blocker-that-filters-youtube-advertisements-on-mojave-safari-versio)

Comment: @anki no it's out of date

Comment: I have tried them and Adguard and none of them work me neither. MacBook Apple silicone (M1) and BigSur 11.6.2 at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdGuard from Appstore works fine for me.

Comment: I've been using it without any problems for 12 days now

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate answer, I use the `hosts` *file* from https://someonewhocares.org/hosts/hosts on my system to block all sorts of known garbage.

I also use [**Little Snitch**](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) to add rules as necessary to catch what the `hosts` *file* does not catch.

While nothing is 100%, nonetheless, these have stopped most of the garbage.

Note however I'm doing this on **macOS Catalina** and have not implemented this under **macOS Big Sur**, but thought it worth mentioning.

<sup>**Note:** I am not affiliated with either of the aforementioned products, just a happy user.</sup>